# Change PDF Annotation properties using iTextSharp C#

Tags: c#, itext

Hi I am adding a *caret annotation* to an already existing PDF using iTextSharp in C#.

Now I want to change some of the annotation's properties, such as **Opacity** of color and **Locked**.

[image]

Comment: Hi i got answer for Locked **annot.Flags = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_LOCKED;**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you have a `PdfAnnotation` object. This is a class that extends `PdfDictionary`.

To lock the annotation defined by this annotation dictionary, you need to set the `PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_LOCKED` flag, for instance with the `setFlags()` method:

```
annot.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_LOCKED);
```

Note that using this method will override the flags that were already defined before.

As for the opacity, that's define by the `ca` entry of the annotation dictionary.

```
annot.put(PdfName.ca, new PdfNumber(0.27));
```

You mention iText as well as iTextSharp, my snippets are lines of Java code. You'll need to apply small changes to the methods if you want to use them in C# code.

Comment: ya fine i am used **annot.Flags = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_LOCKED** for locked, i hope this statement also correct.

Comment: Yes, that what you need in iTextSharp. What I showed was how you'd write the code in iText.