# Change PDF Annotation font size using itext 7

Tags: pdf, fonts, annotations, itext, itext7

My question is a bit similar to this one : [Change PDF Annotation properties using iTextSharp C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538354/change-pdf-annotation-properties-using-itextsharp-c-sharp)

But I want to specifically change font size of pdf annotation using iText 7. I have searched a lot online but haven't been able to find any great examples or documentation regarding this. Following is the code I have used.

```
static void EditAnnot(string PDF)
    {
        string OutPDF = @"C:\Users\AP037X\Desktop\test.pdf";
        iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(PDF), new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(OutPDF));

        iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDictionary pageDict = pdfDoc.GetPage(1).GetPdfObject();
        iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfArray annots = pageDict.GetAsArray(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName.Annots);

        if (annots != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < annots.Size(); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Scan..");
                if (annots.GetAsDictionary(i) == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("1");
                    //return;
                }
                iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfString t = annots.GetAsDictionary(i).GetAsString(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName.Contents);
                if (t == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("2");
                    //return;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(t);
                if (Convert.ToString(t).Trim() == "Change")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Found");
                    Console.WriteLine(annots.Size());
                    iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle rect = annots.GetAsDictionary(i).GetAsRectangle(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName.Rect);
                    iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfString cont =  new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfString("New String");
                    iText.Kernel.Pdf.Annot.PdfFreeTextAnnotation NewAnnot = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.Annot.PdfFreeTextAnnotation(rect,cont);
                    float[] color = { 1f,1f,0f};

                    NewAnnot.SetColor(color);

                    NewAnnot.Put(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName.Contents, new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfString("lion"));
                    NewAnnot.Put(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName.Font, *What to type here?*);
                    annots.Remove(i);
                    annots.Add(i, NewAnnot.GetPdfObject());                    
                }
            }

        }
        pdfDoc.Close();
        CompressPDF(OutPDF);
    }
```

Comment: iText 7 @AmedeeVanGasse

Comment: @mkl if you could help out with this question

Comment: According to your code you take an arbitrary annotation the text content of which happens to be "Change" and replace it by a new FreeText annotation. Is that actually what you want to do, and you really only wonder how to set the font size of this new annotation? Or would you actually prefer to change the existing annotation?